# Can I Use Banner Ad Unit Id for Native Ad in Admob

Tags: android, admob

I want to show native ads in my app.
But in admob I can't create a native ad unit id. When I try native ad with banner unit id, it works - means ads showing.
Can I continue with the banner unit id in native ads?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.
Native express ads was deprecated.
Native ads are only in beta. They're used only by a limited number of publishers. You can try to write to the Google Team. But I'm not sure that you will be included in the beta.
Banner ids are only for banners.

Comment: But why the ads are showing when i add the banner unit id in native ads?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot create a new  native express banner more. And all native express banners will show nothing since March of 2018

Comment: So cant use mative ads now?